# Are there massless excitations when a system is at a $U(1)$ critical point?

Tags: conformal-field-theory, bose-hubbard-model

I am trying to understand the nature of the energy spectrum of a system at various critical point types. For instance, in the following [paper](http://www.fulviofrisone.com/attachments/article/483/030818090032%20An%20Introduction%20To%20Lattice%20Gauge%20Theory%20And%20Spin%20Systems.pdf) the authors shows that for the transverse field Ising model, the critical point has massless excitations because energy is proportional to the momentum. The system involves Z2 symmetry and therefore in the universality class with central charge $1/2$, the energy spectrum has massless excitations.

Now I am trying to consider critical systems that fall into the $U(1) = O(2)$ universality class, whose central charge value is $1$. For this universality class I am focusing on the following [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9906019), which deals with the 1D Bose Hubbard model. In this model's phase diagram, the superfluid phase and the phase boundaries are critical. Here is figure 4, which is a plot of the chemical potentials of adding a particle and adding a hole; note that the dashed lines are linear fits as mentioned in the caption. These chemical potential values make up the phase boundary of the finite system phase diagrams and the y-intercepts make up the the phase boundary of the infinite system phase diagram.

[image]

Suppose the energy spectrum is massless (chemical potential has units of energy). Then we see the following:

$$
E = \hbar \omega = \hbar v k = \hbar v \frac{2\pi}{\lambda} \propto \frac{1}{L}
$$

This could explain why the above figure uses linear fits and it seems possible that the critical phase boundary has massless excitations. **Is it true that critical systems belonging to the universality class with $c = 1$ have massless excitations? If so, why?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally the U(1) symmetry of the vaccum state of the system implies the existence of massless modes (as long as this is an actual symmetry of the system) in a field theoretic description this falls under the name of Goldstones theorem. As far as I remember there is an analysis of a very similar model in David Tongs notes on [Statistical Field theory](https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/sft.html) that covers the theorem.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I can't upvote you though because I do not have enough reputation points.

Answer (score 0):

If a system is critical and flows to a non-trivial CFT in the IR, then it has massless excitations. Any gapped excitation is not compatible with conformal invariance, all the two point functions need to be power laws. The $c=1$ CFT in particular is just the ordinary massless free boson (or Dirac fermion through bosonization), nothing more nor less.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I can't upvote you though because I do not have enough reputation points. Btw, what does IR mean? Also is there a general theorem that states "If a system is critical and flows to a non-trivial CFT in the IR, then it has massless excitations"?

Comment: Yes a CFT means the spectrum is gapless. If there were a gap that would give you a scale that would conflict with conformal invariance. And actually in 2d having $U(1)$ symmetry does not necessarily imply the existence of Goldstone modes.